# How to find equivalent resistance across the leads of this infinite ladder circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image: https://i.imgur.com/Q6wVyzt.png]

I can easily work on a ladder with all resistances equal, since there isn't any problem reducing it into a simple circuit using symmetry argument. How do we do it here though?

My working: I got the recurrence relation $$10^n \times a_{(n-1)} + a_{(n+1)} \times 10^{(n+1)}=a_n * (10^n+10^{(n+1)}+10^{-n}).$$
Plugging this into an online calculator gives an approximate answer of 1.95124922, but I want to find a closed form if that is even possible. Is this recurrence solvable? If yes, please show a complete solution.

**Remark**: This is not a homework question...It is purely out of theoretical interest.

Comment: Think about a equivalent across the battery, let say it is $r^n$ got it now?

Comment: If you assume that for a finite ladder of length N the resistance is $R_N$ then probably some recursive relation can be written that will help to find it in the limit $N \to \infty$.

Comment: @MaximUmansky I did get a recurrence relation, but I am unable to solve it. I have edited my original post.

Comment: You can formulate the solution of this problem as a linear system with an infinite 3-banded matrix so symbolically it can be written as a simple linear matrix equation; but solving this equation (i.e., the infinite size linear system) would be essentially the same as using your recurrence relation. If it was known apriori that a compact form solution exists here then one might try to think harder to try to find it; but otherwise it is probably not worth the time.